# How to delete highlighted cells without indexing up?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete all cells that are highlighted yellow, leaving only the values that are not highlighted. However, every time I delete a highlighted cell, the cell directly below it indexes up into its place, because the value moves up into a different cell it is missed in the loop. Can I prevent cells below highlighted cells from indexing up?

```
Sub DeleteColoredCells()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim sCell As Range
    Set Rng = Range("A1:E4")
        For Each sCell In Rng
            If sCell.Interior.color = vbYellow Then
                sCell.Delete
            End If
        Next sCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `sCell.Delete` try `sCell.Value = ""` if that's what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this if you want to clear the formatting too. If you don't instead of `ClearContents` use `Clear`

```
Sub DeleteColoredCells()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim sCell As Range
    Set Rng = Range("A1:E4")
        For Each sCell In Rng
            If sCell.Interior.color = vbYellow Then
                sCell.ClearContents
            End If
        Next sCell
End Sub
```